# How to config the Ldap authentification in local network entreprise?

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap

I am trying to add authentication with Active Directory in my web application, so that the user can login with their username and password and start a session.

I need to know the necessary parameters to do the configuration.

Comment: Have you try the documentation here : [Authenticating a User with LDAP](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/) ?

Comment: Yes it works!
 But im confused, I need to configure the LDAP server in my application.properties or I need the users data with LDIF format and add to my project ?

Comment: Maybe this article can help you : [Intro to Spring Security LDAP](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-ldap)